# what is happening when installing a software/application in windows os?

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer, exe

i created an application using c# language. this application is doing a task like report generation.i am using that application exe file directly to run the application.i never installed that application in my system. without installation of that application, i can use it in my system.then why people are installing a software/application in systems.please clarify me. so that i can differentiate the MSI installation and direct use of exe file.

Comment: Not everything can be accomplished by simply running a (portable) executable. Some software needs to register components, setup a database, install a service etc. Certain tasks also will require administrative privileges, something you usually only want to allow during setup and not for any running executable.

Comment: If an executable is self contained or has a small set of libraries that are accessed from it's run directory, there isn't much use in installing somewhere unless it is for ease or uniformity of distribution for other users. If you have a more complex executable that references different libraries or needs some system setup before running (Registry changes, framework installation, etc...) then you will want an MSI.

Comment: both comments are informative. thanks. i got it

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to create an installer for even the simplest apps.  Consistent install, uninstall, repair, patch, upgrade, downgrade, entries in Win32_Product / Programs and Features, enterprise distribution, encapsulation / automation are all important.  Besides, I can create a simple installer and add it to the build in 5 minutes  so why not do it?

Comment: Christopher Painter,yes we can use installation to avail all these benefits like you said in above.

Answer (score 1):

*Install* in cs jargon means guided setup, so what you do is already, basically, installing. Installing may involve much more complicated steps than simple copy/paste of bin directory or unzipping in some folder. installation process may contain the below processes:

1. Controlling user license
2. Registry key control
3. Database creation
4. Com components registration
   ....
   and much more.

But the core concept remains the same: guided setup of all necessary components of your program to run it properly. So, if the only thing *your* program needs is a binaries folder, copy/paste is your install.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is called an "xcopy" deployment.  It was all the rage when .NET came out but it has serious limitations.

Windows Installer (MSI) is a windows platform service / SDK that aimed to create a declarative framework for consistent installer behavior.  Simply put instead of learning how to write script to automate install/uninstall (and making a lot of mistakes along the way)  you leverage MSI to tell it I have a product named X with feature Y that has these files Z in these directories along with a shortcut and some registry entries and let MSI do the rest for you.